# Array memory allocation in C#

Tags: c#

I was wandering which way of doing below code is better :

```
a)

    byte[] tmp = BitConverter.GetBytes(Number)

b) 
    byte[] tmp = new byte[sizeof(Number)]
    tmp = BitConverter.GetBytes(Number)
```

Is it necessary to use dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: What is `Number`? Does `sizeof(Number)` compiles?

Comment: Number was an example of some numeric object

Answer (score 4):

Definitely a).

b) creates two arrays, the first of which is completely unnecessary and is thrown away right after being initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Actually second one is *redundant*, because `GetBytes` returns a new array so you are throwing away the first array you created...

Answer (score 1):

The first is better for two reasons:

1. It is more readable
2. In sample b the first allocation is thrown away as `tmp` is re-assigned to the return value of `GetBytes`